# Failed to load D:\xampp\htdocs\wisata\storage\framework\cache\laravel-excel\laravel-excel-TnuNdoEqijuZ2ap1N6clNw6ZAhOykcsr.html as a DOM Document

Tags: excel, laravel, export-to-excel, laravel-excel

I use export excel from website : https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html to make the final report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J78Sw.jpg)

I'm using from view to export the query ('kecamatan') that exists in each table. But when I press the export button, an error like the one above appears and showing the error in this section:

```
  if ($loaded === false) {

        throw new Exception('Failed to load ' . $filename . ' as a DOM Document', 0, $e ?? null);

    }
```

I have tried everything for resolving this issue but nothing worked.

```
php artisan cache:clear | php artisan view:clear | php artisan route:clear | php artisan config:clear
```

what should i do to solve this excel export problem.

MyController :

```
public function exportlaporanakhir()
{
    return Excel::download(new ExportLaporanAkhir, 'data-laporan-akhir-sektor.xlsx');
}
```

MyExport

```
public function view(): View
{

    return view('Dashboard.Laporan.Akhir.LaporanFinalindex', [
        'laporanfinal' => Wisata::select('kecamatan', Wisata::raw('count(wisata.id) as jumlah_wisata'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal2' => Transportasi::select('kecamatan', Transportasi::raw('count(transportasi.id) as jumlah_transportasi'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal3' => Penginapan::select('kecamatan', Penginapan::raw('count(penginapan.id) as jumlah_penginapan'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal4' => Mall::select('kecamatan', Mall::raw('count(mall.id) as jumlah_mall'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal5' => Restaurant::select('kecamatan', Restaurant::raw('count(restaurant.id) as jumlah_restaurant'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal6' =>  Bioskop::select('kecamatan', Bioskop::raw('count(bioskop.id) as jumlah_bioskop'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal7' => Spa::select('kecamatan', Spa::raw('count(spa.id) as jumlah_spa'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal8' => Ukm::select('kecamatan', Ukm::raw('count(ukm.id) as jumlah_ukm'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal9' => Media::select('kecamatan', Media::raw('count(media.id) as jumlah_media'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),

        'laporanfinal10' => Komunitas::select('kecamatan', Komunitas::raw('count(komunitas.id) as jumlah_komunitas'))
            ->groupBy('kecamatan')
            ->OrderBy('kecamatan')
            ->get(),
    ]);
```

}

MyView

```
    <!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2 class="card-title">DASHBOARD LAPORAN AKHIR WISATA</h2>
                    </div>

                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                        <div class="card-tools mb-3 ml-3 mt-3"><a href="{{ route('exportlaporanakhir') }}"
                                class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-print">
                                    CETAK LAPORAN </i></a></div>
                        <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"> Tambah Data </i></a> -->
                        <table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 35px 0px">NO</th>
                                    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 35px 0px">
                                        SEKTOR</th>
                                    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center">KECAMATAN</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Bumiaji</th>
                                    <th>Batu</th>
                                    <th>Junrejo</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @php
                                    $no = 1;
                                @endphp
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Destinasi</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal as $lapor)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor->jumlah_wisata }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Transportasi</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal2 as $index => $lapor2)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor2->jumlah_transportasi }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Penginapan</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal3 as $index => $lapor3)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor3->jumlah_penginapan }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Mall / Pasar</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal4 as $index => $lapor4)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor4->jumlah_mall }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Restaurant & Cafe</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal5 as $index => $lapor5)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor5->jumlah_restaurant }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Bioskop</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal6 as $index => $lapor6)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor6->jumlah_bioskop }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>SPA</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal7 as $index => $lapor7)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor7->jumlah_spa }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>UKM</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal8 as $index => $lapor8)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor8->jumlah_ukm }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Media</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal9 as $index => $lapor9)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor9->jumlah_media }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="item">{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>Komunitas</td>
                                    @foreach ($laporanfinal10 as $index => $lapor10)
                                        <td>{{ $lapor10->jumlah_komunitas }}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                    <div class="card-footer clearfix">
                        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-0 float-right">
                            {{-- {{ $laporanpenginapan1->links() }} --}}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Comment: i think your view should contain `table` only